# How can I query the number of unread SMS in android

Tags: android, sms

Can you please tell me how can i query the number of unread SMS in android programmically?

How can I implement the SMS unread count like [this](http://android.kanokgems.com/sms-unread-count/) link:

Comment: The accepted answer is really not an answer to the above question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718687/get-number-of-unread-sms for the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that lets you read messages as they arrive.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage [] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";

        if (myBundle != null)
        {
            Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
            {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                strMessage += " : ";
                strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                strMessage += "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need to notify every time I get a SMS. I am interested in reading how many SMS are unread and how many voice mail are unread.

Comment: I understand, but it will be easy to modify this code to persist a count of every new messages that arrive, so then you can query it from your main activity.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code:

mSMSReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
  Intent registerReceiver = registerReceiver(mSMSReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION));

But when I test it by sending SMS in emulator, the onReceive() never  get called.

Comment: You need to register your broadcast receiver in your manifest file first.

Answer (score 2):

The [API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) show a constant that you should be able to look for to figure out which messages are [received and unread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#STATUS_ON_SIM_UNREAD).

[This article](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/) shows somebody interacting with the SmsMessage class, which might give you some pointers.