# Get number of unread sms

Tags: android

How can I get the number of unread sms in android?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Need to execute a simple query to SMS ContentProvider. Here is a working example:

```
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();
c.deactivate();
```

You will also need the READ_SMS permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Keep in mind that the SMS content provider isn't actually part of the SDK, and this code is not guaranteed to work on all past, present and future devices.

Comment: Note: this requires the READ_SMS permission!

Comment: getContentResolver() must be called from an existing context. To anyone in the future coming here for an answer, the proper syntax is `Cursor c = context.getContentResolver()`

Comment: can I get unread messages which we received in the last hour?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found out:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
    new String[] {
        "count(_id)",
    },
    "read = 0",
    null,
    null
);
c.moveToFirst();
int unreadMessagesCount = c.getInt(0);
```

Comment: can I get unread messages which we received in the last hour?