# How to get SMS statistics (unread messages) without extra permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, sms

If permissions were not an issue, I could solve this by simply reading the content of SMS: [Get number of unread sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718687/get-number-of-unread-sms)

However this requires `READ_SMS` permission, and this is very broad one -- and I would not like any user freaking out. After all getting the number of unread SMSes is pretty benign operation.

So -- how can I just **read** statistics of SMS (total messages, unread messages) without triggering any permission conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. You need to have READ_SMS permission to do any operations involving the SMS'es.