# How to get the number of already read messages in android?

Tags: android, sms

In my app,i want to give the user info about the number of already read and unread messages from inbox.I have searched and found out that there is no such content://sms/read is present in android api.I have tried this code till now:

```
        Uri number_of_sms_read = Uri.parse("content://sms/read");
        Cursor c = ShowTheMessages.this.getContentResolver().query(number_of_sms_read, null,null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        NumberOfSmsReadInInbox = c.getCount();
```

Can you please tell me is it possible to get the count of read and unread messages in android?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can take a look at this question which is the reverse of yours: [Get number of unread sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718687/get-number-of-unread-sms)

It provides the WHERE condition `"read = 0"` to the query, so you might want to supply a `"read = 1"`.

Comment: Working like charm.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 1", null, null);
int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();
c.deactivate();
```