# How to make difference between read and unread message

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

In my app I need to get sms from specific number to activity.I got it.Now how could I differentiate read and unread messages of that specific number.And also I need to show unread message count out off total messages from that number in my previous activity.Can anyone tell me how can I accomplish this task?I tried the following code,

```
 Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id",
           "address", "person", "date","body", "type" },"read=0", null,   null);
```

But this return 0 rows in listview.I also tried to get the total number of messages by using

```
msgcount=list.size();
```

How can I get the `msgcount` value to my previous activity. I declared the variable as public static. But it shows 0 while the listsize is 11.
Please Help!

Comment: you can use row query

Answer (score 0):

For unread message `read=0` for more details follow this link [Get number of unread sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718687/get-number-of-unread-sms)

Comment: it will get unread sms from all numbers.But I want to get it for specific mobile number...

Comment: Put where condition in query : - getContentResolver().query(uri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" },"read=0", put where condition,   null);

Comment: when I gave read=0,it loads only unread messages in my list...But I wan to load both read and unread msgs and wan to differentiate them...

Comment: after getting list all rows , you can check which are read or unread by value of status flag

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can add  sms_status flag as a column , it's default value 0 . 
when you will finish to read sms ,update  flag and value will be 1.

when you will query unread sms then check sms_status flag 0 and phone number

msgcount=list.size();
if(msgcount > 0){

for(SMS sms:list){
String smsFlag  = sms.getSmsFlag();
if(smsFlag  .equals("0")){
// read sms

}else{

//unread sms
}
}
}
```

Comment: I need a query that will retrieve both total and unread messages count.Then only I have to set the flag to differentiate them